# Automate calculations in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have large file and I need to calculate the time difference for different records. For illustration , MWE provided

The data data frame df:

```
       st   time     from  to   type   size flg         fid     src       dst  no   ID
        + 0.163944    2    1      a     40  -------      1      2.4      5.4   0    10
        + 0.215400    2    1      a     40  -------      1      2.4      5.4   1    28
        + 0.239528    2    1      t     40  -------      1      2.4      5.4   0    37
        + 0.287784    2    1      t   1040  -------      1      2.4      5.4   1    62
        + 0.287784    2    1      t   1040  -------      1      2.4      5.4   2    63
        ..........    .  .      ...   .. .......      .       .        ..   .    ..
        # here should be some more lines with different value such as
        - 0.487784    3    0      t  1040 -------        4      2.8      7.4   2    23
        # the above line will be filtered out by the conditions-just ignore it
        ..........    .  .      ...   .. .......      .       .        ..   .    .. 
        r 0.188072    0    5      a    40 -------      1         2.4      5.4   0    10
        r 0.239528    0    5      a    40 -------      1         2.4      5.4   1    28
        r 0.263656    0    5      t    40 -------      1         2.4      5.4   0    37
        r 0.317128    0    5      t  1040 -------      1         2.4      5.4   1    62
        r 0.318792    0    5      t  1040 -------      1         2.4      5.4   2    63
```

Condition 1: for each record starts with "+" the 'ID' will be unique. The "src" , "dst", and "from" are added to the condition. Based on this information, the "time" field will be recorded as the start in an array (i.e array[ID]=time).

condition 2: for each record starts with "r" the 'ID' will be checked . Based on this information, the required time difference will be : current "time" - array[ID].

I have created the R code and it worked. However, I'm using a fixed src and dst values. the format of the src: x.y , where x is always =2 and y is changing ( i.e. y=0,1,2,3,4,.......). Also, the dst: z.f , where z and f are changing (i.e. could be 4.3,5.2,6.100....)

The R code:

```
src<-"2.4"  # this value should be automated like 2.y. Any suggestions !!! 
dst<-"5.4"  # this value should be automated like z.f
ReqTime<-0
timeHolder<-c()

#start
start<-df[df[, "st"] == "+" &  
        df[, "from"] == 2 &  
        # the src and dst should be automated 
        df[, "src"] == src &        
        df[, "dst"] == dst,]

timeHolder[start$ID]<-start$time

 #end
 end<-df[df[, "st"] == "r" &  
          df[, "from"] == 0 &
          df[, "src"] == src &
          df[, "dst"] == dst,]


if(!is.null(timeHolder[end$ID])){
  ReqTime<- end$time- timeHolder[end$pktID]

 }

cat("Time from ",src,"--",dst,": ",ReqTime,"\n")
```

}

The expected output:

```
Time from  2.4 -- 5.4 :  0.024128 0.024128 0.024128 0.029344 0.031008
```

or much appreciated if I can get output like:

```
Time from  2.4 -- 5.4 :  mean( 0.024128 0.024128 0.024128 0.029344 0.031008) which is =0.0265472
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly what you want, you could `aggregate` your data:

```
#your data plus some extra
DF <- read.table(text = 'st   time     from  to   type   size flg         fid     src       dst  no   ID
    + 0.163944    2    1      a     40  -------      1      2.4      5.4   0    10
    + 0.215400    2    1      a     40  -------      1      2.4      5.4   1    28
    + 0.239528    2    1      t     40  -------      1      2.4      5.4   0    37
    + 0.287784    2    1      t   1040  -------      1      2.4      5.4   1    62
    + 0.287784    2    1      t   1040  -------      1      2.4      5.4   2    63
    + 0.297784    2    1      t   1040  -------      1      2.5      5.7   2    65
    + 0.307984    2    1      t   1040  -------      1      2.5      5.7   2    67
    + 0.325784    2    1      t   1040  -------      1      2.5      5.7   2    68
    #..........    .  .      ...   .. .......      .       .        ..   .    ..
    # here should be some more lines with different value such as
    #- 0.487784    3    0      t  1040 -------        4      2.8      7.4   2    23
    # the above line will be filtered out by the conditions-just ignore it
    #..........    .  .      ...   .. .......      .       .        ..   .    .. 
    r 0.188072    0    5      a    40 -------      1         2.4      5.4   0    10
    r 0.239528    0    5      a    40 -------      1         2.4      5.4   1    28
    r 0.263656    0    5      t    40 -------      1         2.4      5.4   0    37
    r 0.317128    0    5      t  1040 -------      1         2.4      5.4   1    62
    r 0.318792    0    5      t  1040 -------      1         2.4      5.4   2    63 
    r 0.328792    0    5      t  1040 -------      1         2.5      5.7   2    65
    r 0.338792    0    5      t  1040 -------      1         2.5      5.7   2    67
    r 0.348792    0    5      t  1040 -------      1         2.5      5.7   2    68',
    header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)

aggregate(DF$time, list(src = DF$src, dst = DF$dst, ID = DF$ID), diff)
#  src dst ID        x
#1 2.4 5.4 10 0.024128
#2 2.4 5.4 28 0.024128
#3 2.4 5.4 37 0.024128
#4 2.4 5.4 62 0.029344
#5 2.4 5.4 63 0.031008
#6 2.5 5.7 65 0.031008
#7 2.5 5.7 67 0.030808
#8 2.5 5.7 68 0.023008
```

Also, by naming `aggregate`'s return `aggDF`, you can call a second `aggregate` to show the results clearly:

```
aggDF <- aggregate(DF$time, list(src = DF$src, dst = DF$dst, ID = DF$ID), diff)

aggregate(aggDF$x, list(src = aggDF$src, dst = aggDF$dst), list)
#  src dst                                                x
#1 2.4 5.4 0.024128, 0.024128, 0.024128, 0.029344, 0.031008
#2 2.5 5.7                     0.031008, 0.030808, 0.023008
```

Comment: Your approach is nearly close. However,The DF$st could be ("+","-","r") in the DF, how to include it as a condition? also if I want to add more condition such as DF$size==1040, not sure it works with aggregate unless keep re-aggregating. That's why I was putting the conditions separated in variables (i.e. start and end). Maybe aggregate will not be flexible for future requirements and amendments !! haven't used aggregate much before !!

Comment: In order to check the results, I have tried to do it in your approach. I did the first aggregate with more condition. Then I added more filters to the aggregated data. Then I was trying to do the re-aggregation to put as list or calculate mean. I'm getting the "arguments imply differing number of rows error". On the above example data it worked (I guess because it is ideal for each "+" there is "r" , but large file is not working. See my update on your answer.

Comment: That's why I was trying to avoid using aggregation and use my logic above.

Comment: @SimpleNEasy: For further conditions you can -e.g.- `aggregate(DF$time, list(src = DF$src, dst = DF$dst, ID = DF$ID, size = DF$size), diff)` and then subset those `aggregate`d dataframe using -let's say- `size == 1040`. Or you could subset your data at first and then perform an `aggregat`ion on the subset. E.g. `subsetDF <- subset(DF, st == "+" & size == "1040" | st == "r" & size == "1040")` ; `aggregate(subsetDF$time, list(src = subsetDF$src, dst = subsetDF$dst, ID = subsetDF$ID), diff)`. Are these of any use? Maybe you could write a wrapper of `subset` and input conditions as arguments.

Comment: @SimpleNEasy: I, just, noticed your suggested edit in my answer. For the mean you could use `aggregate(aggDF$x, list(src = aggDF$src, dst = aggDF$dst), mean)` on the `aggregate`d dataframe I have named as `aggDF`.

Comment: I guess that was like my suggestions in your answer. Now the main problem is still not solved, have you checked my second comment regarding the error `arguments imply differing number of rows` which I get, when I use last aggregate for list or mean.

Comment: @SimpleNEasy: I can't really tell about the error if I haven't seen a sample of your data that depicts your whole data correctly. Maybe, if you edit the question to add, a part of your data that will produce the same errors to me too?